# Angular resizable element - added dynamically

Tags: angular, resizable

Maybe someone used this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-resizable-element ?

I need to add this function dynamically to my div after click event. But I haven`t idea how.

Now I have something like this:

```
this.renderer.setAttribute(destinationElement, 'mwlResizable', "");
this.renderer.setAttribute(destinationElement,'ng-reflect-enable-ghost-resize', 'true');

const placeleftDiv = this.renderer.createElement('div');
this.renderer.addClass(placeleftDiv, 'resize-handle-left');
this.renderer.setAttribute(placeleftDiv, 'mwlResizeHandle', " ");
this.renderer.setAttribute(placeleftDiv, 'ng-reflect-resize-edges', destinationElement.toString());
const placeRightDiv = this.renderer.createElement('div');
this.renderer.addClass(placeRightDiv, 'resize-handle-right');
this.renderer.setAttribute(placeRightDiv, 'mwlResizeHandle', " ");
this.renderer.appendChild(destinationElement, placeleftDiv);
this.renderer.appendChild(destinationElement, placeRightDiv);
```

Best regards!

Comment: Recently someone ask about resize a ng-bootstrap modal, you can check the response in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68525239/ngbootstrap-angular-8-modal-resizable-and-draggable/68610519#68610519)

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
I use clear js code and add this as library to my project, that`s easier for me.
[link](https://medium.com/the-z/making-a-resizable-div-in-js-is-not-easy-as-you-think-bda19a1bc53d)

Comment: For Angular, I prefer use `[ngStyle]` and use `ViewChildren` to get the "resizers" but yours it's a nice method :). NOTE: If you want to work in touched screen remember to subscribe to touchstart, touchend and touchmove