# Resize div box in angular from the opposite corner

Tags: css, angular, typescript, calculator, resizable

• I just want to resize a square from the left not the right

• Here is the code I used:

[My Stackblitz Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fte9g8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

• My desired result:

[image]

• Thanks for your help.

Comment: you need, futhermore translate, change the with and the heigth. Some like this another [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68525239/ngbootstrap-angular-8-modal-resizable-and-draggable/68610519#68610519)

Comment: I don't know that's will solve your problem but you can draw an other box small red on the blue with z-index sup to appear like position change of the left bottom corner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying many solutions I recommende to use the package [angular2-draggable](https://xieziyu.github.io/angular2-draggable/#/resizable/events) which allows users to resize from all sides.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not a good practice to do this, but make your selector `.dragHandle.rb` like this:

```
.dragHandle.rb {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  cursor: nwse-resize;
  transform: translate3d(0px, 235px, 235px) !important;
}
```

Comment: I want to resize from the left not to fix the red square !!